# Why does matlab write the numbers in the symbolic functions this way?

Tags: matlab

Why is the number 0.9947 written 8959626780035403/9007199254740992 in the symbolic function P and what can I do to change it back to 0.9947?

```
syms x;
f = sin(x);
f = matlabFunction(f);
n = 3;
a = -pi/2;
b = pi/2
X = linspace(a, b, n + 1);
Y = f(X);
y = MetDirecta(X,Y)
syms x Pn
P = 0;
for i = 1:n+1
    P = P + (y(i))*x^(i - 1);

end
P
```

```
function [y] = MetDirecta(X, Y)

    n = length(X);

    for i = 1:n
        A(i,1) = 1;
    end
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 2:n
            A(i,j) = X(i)^(j - 1);
        end
    end

    solutie = GaussPivTot(A, Y');

    y = solutie;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The symbolic math in matlab wants to provide you an exact representation. You can convert the result to a float with `double()`.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html